# Exchanging integrals with derivatives in Hoeffding's lemma Question

Tags: real-analysis, integration, statistics

I am looking at the Hoeffding's inequality proof and I have a question regarding taking derivatives of the cumulant.

So given $\psi_X(t)=\log E[e^{Xt}]$, we'd like to show that $\psi_X^{'}(t)=\frac{E[Xe^{Xt}]}{E[e^{Xt}]}$ and $\psi_X^{''}(t)=\frac{E[X^2e^{Xt}]E[e^{Xt}]-E[Xe^{Xt}]^2}{E[e^{Xt}]^2}$.

This seems like standard calculus, but we are actually changing the order of the expectation and the derivative in obtaining the results. I am familiar with the measure theory version here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule. So is this a simple application of this version using the fact that $X$ is bounded on some $[a,b]$ interval, or is this valid for another reason?

Comment: Yes you are right